# Ruby/Capybara:-Can we Automate Omniture Test cases using Cucumber with Capybara&selenium?

Tags: capybara

Can we Automate Omniture Test cases using Cucumber with Capybara&selenium?If yes can anyone show me what will be the steps.
I am trying hard since many days to Automate Omniture test cases where events are generated but dont know how to Automate it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? What are omniture tets in your case?

Answer (score 1):

You should have access to the javascript variables via the browser. Visit your site and open up the console.Type in s.events and see what the value is. So, say you want to populate s.events with a value after the user clicks a button, but you don't want to fire a page load event then as long as you know what the values for the click and page load events should be then your test would look like:

```
Given I visit a page
When I click a button
Then I should see "this" and not "that"

Then /^I should see "(.*?)" and not "(.*?)"$/ do |good, bad|
   events = page.evaluate_script("s.events")
   events.should include(good), "expected events to include #{good} but saw #{events}"
   events.should not_include(bad), "did not expect to see #{bad} in events"
```